# To achieve Grand total for the retrieved column in a datatable generated using Soql

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, reporting, dynamic-visualforce

I have created a VF tab in which i have retrieved the data with a SOQL statement and displayed the same with VF page using a datatable to make it as a customized report. I can't find a proper solution for the Grandtotal of each and every column for data retrieved and displayed in the VF tab.Kindly help me with this providing a solution or a sample code if any.

**Required Output :**

```
      ColA   ColB
       1       3
       5       5
       5       6
       7       8
 Grand -----------
 Total 18      22
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a quick&dirty solution you can generate totals on the fly just using an [`apex:variable`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_variable.htm) (note that if you need the more complex calculations of the totals it is better to use apex for that):

Apex class. Here just reading a data:

```
public with sharing class MyTest {

    public List<Account> accounts { get; set; }

    public MyTest(){
        accounts = [select id, name, number1__c, number2__c 
                    from account 
                    where number1__c != null and 
                    number2__c != null];
    }
}
```

Page. Here using apex:variable to generate a total and then using some simple javascript to set generated value to the footer:

```
<apex:page controller="MyTest">
<apex:form >

<!-- Need this variables for totals generation -->
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total1"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="total2"/>

<apex:pageBlock title="Totals">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="item" id="list1">

    <apex:column value="{!item.name}" width="20%"/>

    <apex:column headerValue="Number1">
        <apex:outputField value="{!item.number1__c}" />

        <!-- Generating a first total -->
        <apex:variable var="total1" value="{!total1 + item.number1__c}" />

        <!-- Footer of the first Cell -->>
        <apex:facet name="footer">
            Total: <span class="t1"></span>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="Number2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!item.number2__c}" />
        <apex:variable var="total2" value="{!total2 + item.number2__c}" />
        <apex:facet name="footer">
            Total: <span class="t2"></span>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

<script>
    // Here we will set the generated subtotals to the footer cells
    document.getElementsByClassName('t1')[0].innerHTML = '{!total1}';
    document.getElementsByClassName('t2')[0].innerHTML = '{!ROUND(total2,0)}';
</script>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.mast0r for your instantaneous help.

Comment: mastOr - what do you make of the line in the VF doc under apex:variable that states `Note:<apex:variable> does not support reassignment inside of an iteration component, such as <apex:dataTable> or <apex:repeat>. The result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the <apex:variable> as a counter, is unsupported and undefined` ?

Comment: I know, but it works very well for years! Just undocumented feature I think :)