# Formatting the variable used for Grand total for the retrieved column in a datatable generated using Soql

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, pageblocktable

I am currently using the visual force component  to get the grand total of my pageblocktable column as referred too in this question ['To achieve Grand total for the retrieved column in a datatable generated using Soql'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/to-achieve-grand-total-for-the-retrieved-column-in-a-datatable-generated-using-s/64617#64617) 
Please and help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
[image]
Here is the total. How can I format this in to dollar amount? Nothing is working, please advise.

[image]

Comment: Jonathan, what precisely isn't working ? Maybe we can better understand if you show us your code and current progress or attempts.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: This is the code it is all visual force.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code which could help you in formatting total value :

  `<script>
   function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
    // Here we will set the generated subtotals to the footer cells
    document.getElementsByClassName('t4')[0].innerHTML 
                                       = '$ '+numberWithCommas({!total4});
  </script>`

This will allow you to maintain comma in between total value.
Example Total: 397423.66 will be displayed as 'Total: $ 397,423.66'

Comment: hot diggidy daym! Thats some sweet code right there! All those escapes n stuff. Impressive!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to add an `apex:param` between the `apex:outputText` tags that contains the value you wish to format.

```
<apex:outputText value"{0,number,$###,###,##0.00}">
    Total
    <apex:param value="{!total4}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work because total4 is an apex variable but I got it figured out the Javascript just will not show when it is in being rendered as a PDF now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the GrandTotal using Javascript, why not add the $ during that point?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('t4')[0].innerHTML = '${!total4}';
```