# Format <apex:variable> used in VF page

Tags: visualforce, formatting

need to know how to format  in vf page.
Im having variable to display total from chart.
The total displayed need to have comma (ex:95,000)

the below code can be used to format outputText. 
But suggest me how to format variable

`<apex:outputText> value="{0, number, ###,###,###}"
      <apex:param value="{!data}"></apex:param>
</apex:outputText>`

Here is the VF page excerpt:

```
<apex:column > 
  <apex:facet name="header">
     <apex:outputText value="Header" /> 
  </apex:facet> 
  <apex:outputText value="{!data.data4}"/> //column data from controller    
  <apex:variable var="total" value="{!total + data.data4}" /> //variable used in vf page to get column total 

  <apex:facet name="footer"> 
    <span class="t4"></span> 
  </apex:facet> 
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code which helped me in formatting total value :

```
<script>
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
// Here we will set the generated subtotals to the footer cells
document.getElementsByClassName('t4')[0].innerHTML = '$ '+numberWithCommas({!total4});
</script>
```

This will allow to have comma in between total value of `<apex:variable>`.

Example Total: 397423.66 will be displayed as `Total: $ 397,423.66`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the number is an integer in apex controller.
You will not beed to format using output text.

You can format it as:

```
Integer number = 95000;
System.debug('Formatted output ' + number.format());
```

Did you tried this way:

```
<apex:column > 
        <apex:facet name="header">
              <apex:outputText value="Header" /> 
         </apex:facet> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!data.data4}"/>

        <apex:variable var="total" value="{!total + data.data4}" /> 
         <!--variable used in vf page to get column total -->
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}">
               <apex:param value="{!total}" />
        </apex:outputText>

        <apex:facet name="footer"> 
           <span class="t4"></span> 
        </apex:facet> 
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Im using `<apex:variable>` in VF page to get  sum of Integer (total) of chart column. The value is nowhere used in controller.

Comment: @Naveen did you try using the var name in `output:text` exact place where you have wirtten `number`?

Comment: `<apex:column >
 <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputText value="Header" />  </apex:facet>
<apex:outputText value="{!data.data4}"/> //column data from controller <apex:variable var="total" value="{!total + data.data4}" /> //variable used in vf page to get column total
<apex:facet name="footer">
<span class="t4"></span>
</apex:facet> </apex:column>`

Comment: above is sample code which im using for table.. sorry for rough comment there.. new here.. dont know how to enter next line..

Comment: I have used below link as sample to obtain column total 
[link]http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/to-achieve-grand-total-for-the-retrieved-column-in-a-datatable-generated-using-s
i need to format the total value (ex: 95440 -> 95,440)

Comment: @Naveen I updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: yes i tried the above method before but formatting dosen't happen

Comment: @Naveen Try with foramting only `{0, number, ###,###,###}` in place of `{0, number, 000,000.00}` perhaps the decimal formatting problem.

Comment: tried even that.. but no success :(