# Getting always zero as total in apex:variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, global-variables

I am getting always 0 as a result of total.
I am using apex:vairable, initialing it before apex:block. Inside the apex:block  I am adding the field of object i.e number type with apex:variable and fetching it's value {!total} inside the apex:block.
My code is:

```
 <apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total"/> 
       <apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable title="Your Total" value="{!selectedWrapperList}" var="wrapRec" rendered="{!selectedList}" >
<apex:column ><apex:outputText value="{!wrapRec.Place_Price__c}" />
    <apex:variable var="total"  value="{(!total + wrapRec.Place_Price__c)}" />
    <apex:facet name="footer"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{!total}"/>
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
<apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

I am following the code in below link:
[code followed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/to-achieve-grand-total-for-the-retrieved-column-in-a-datatable-generated-using-s)

Any assistance with code are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ,it's not guaranteed to work with pageblocktable. In fact, SF does not support its use for iteration. However, if you want to use this , please use it with repeat where there are high possibility to work. I have tried below and it's worked

```
<apex:page controller="accountlist">
       <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="total"/> 
           <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:repeat value="{!acclist}" var="v">
               <apex:variable var="total"  value="{!total + 1}" />
                   {!total}
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>

Contorller

    public class accountlist {

        public list<account> getAccList() {
            return [select id from Account limit 20];
        }

    }
```

Comment: I want to add the field instead of counting and I have tried this code and it's working fine.   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/to-achieve-grand-total-for-the-retrieved-column-in-a-datatable-generated-using-s

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your binding expression. This:

```
value="{(!total + wrapRec.Place_Price__c)}"
```

Should be this:

```
value="{!total + wrapRec.Place_Price__c}"
```

Comment: This might fix your problem in your previous question too...

Comment: by changing this: it's giving me error message NOT is not a valid function.

Comment: removed the brackets - try again.

Comment: still getting 0

Comment: Either `wrapRec.Place_Price__c` is always 0, is not a number - or is a decimal perhaps, or you need to change your `<apex:variable>` to be an integer. It just has to be that. Can you test this by using a normal `Integer` defined in the controller? You just have to work out what your values are - that's how you debug. I can't help you any more that this, sorry.

Comment: My Place_Price__c is Number(6, 2) and all the fields have the value >0. It's okay @CaspNZ thank you for answering.