# Table in Revenue Object

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I've created a object called Revenue in Salesforce and there i stack all the revenue per month. What I want to do is summarize all the revenue that is there. For that reason I've created a roll-up summary field in salesforce where it summarize the Rev.Share Dev.Rev and SaaS Rev. Now I want those fields to be added into the revenue Tab. For that reason I've created a table:

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr class="headerRow">
         <td ><b> TOTAL REVENUE </b></td>
         </tr>
    <tr class="headerRow">
         <th>Rev. Share</th>
         <th>Dev. Rev.</th>
         <th>SaaS. Rev.</th>
     </tr>

     <tr class="dataRow" >
         <td><b><apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Summary_Field_Rev_Share__c}"/></b></td>
         <td><apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Summary_Field_Dev_Rev__c}"/></td>
         <td><apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Summary_Field_Saas_Rev__c}"/></td>
     </tr>


</table>
```

And that table shows the values like this :
[image]

And what I want is those values to be aligned below the main values shown in the picture below:
[image]

For the note I want those to be positioned in that way so that if i open them in another resolution they won't shift left or right depending on the resolution.

Here is all the code that i am using just for this tab.

```
<apex:tab label="Revenue" name="RevShare" id="tabRevShare" >
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="RevShares__r"  />
         <div>
      <table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
         <tr class="headerRow" >
         <th>Total Revenue</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="dataRow" >
         <td ></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
     <table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">

    <tr class="headerRow" >
         <th colspan="3"></th>
         <th>Rev. Share</th>
         <th>Dev. Rev.</th>
         <th>SaaS. Rev.</th>
     </tr>

     <tr class="dataRow" >
         <td colspan="3"></td>
         <td><b><apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Summary_Field_Rev_Share__c}"/></b></td>
         <td><apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Summary_Field_Dev_Rev__c}"/></td>
         <td><apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Summary_Field_Saas_Rev__c}"/></td>
     </tr>


</table>
         </div>

      </apex:tab>
```

If anyone can help me do this I will be really grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an apex:pageBlockTable for your Revenue object, you can add a footer to a table column as described in [To achieve Grand total for the retrieved column in a datatable generated using Soql](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/to-achieve-grand-total-for-the-retrieved-column-in-a-datatable-generated-using-s). See towards the end of the [apex:column](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm) documentation for the official description of the feature.

So for your case it would be something like:

```
<apex:column value={!r.Rev_Share__c}">
    <apex:facet name="footer">
        Total: {!Account.Summary_Field_Rev_Share__c}
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

You will have to add your own CSS to right align the content.

I also see in the [apex:column](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm) documentation that there is a `footerValue` attribute (and other footer attributes) that might also be sufficient.

Comment: Hey Keith, Thank you for your reply. I am not using apex:pageBlockTable. Do you think is better to use that or my code shown above? How can i edit my code so that i can get what i want?

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski Oh I see now you are using apex:relatedList. I don't know of how to inject footer elements into the columns there. I would use the apex:pageBlockTable but that would mean a bit of messy stuff to provide and style the Edit and Del links if you need them (do you)?

Comment: yea i will really want to have the edit/del options available as well. Maybe on click or just the actions edit/delete

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski If you are a jQuery whizz you could use JavaScript to duplicate the last table row, remove its table cell content and insert your summary values instead.

Comment: thank you for your effort. It will be hard for me to do that since i am not javascript Wiz. I can try but for start I don't know how to get the table id from salesforce :(