# How to display grand total in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Good morning, I would like to ask on how to display grand total cost in visualforce page using code below.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're never adding the 2 sums together...

Change this line

`<apex:variable var="Total" value="{!SOAd.Rate_Vat_Ex__c}"/>`

to

`<apex:variable var="Total" value="{!Total + SOAd.Rate_Vat_Ex__c}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using the `apex:variable` for displaying totals in footer facet of column in `apex:pageBlockTable` won't work without using some JavaScript hack as mentioned in [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/20568/6891)

If you want to use above approach, then you need to make changes as mentioned in Boris' answer.

And if you don't want to use JavaScript hack, you can use following approach which doesn't involve any JavaScript.

// example class

```
public class SOController {

    public List<ProductWrapper> products {get; set;}

    public SOController() {
        products = new List<ProductWrapper>();
        products.add(new ProductWrapper(
            'Test 1', 'Test description 1', 10, 5
        ));
        products.add(new ProductWrapper(
            'Test 2', 'Test description 2', 20, 4
        ));
        products.add(new ProductWrapper(
            'Test 3', 'Test description 3', 30, 3
        ));
        products.add(new ProductWrapper(
            'Test 4', 'Test description 4', 40, 2
        ));
        products.add(new ProductWrapper(
            'Test 5', 'Test description 5', 50, 1
        ));
    }

    public class ProductWrapper {
        public String name {get; set;}
        public String description {get; set;}
        public Decimal unitPrice {get; set;}
        public Integer quantity {get; set;}

        public ProductWrapper(String name, String description, Decimal unitPrice, Integer quantity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
    }

    // controller method to get gross total of products
    public Decimal getGrossTotal(){
        Decimal grossTotal = 0;
        for(ProductWrapper pw : products) {
            grossTotal += (pw.unitPrice * pw.quantity);
        }
        return grossTotal;
    }
}
```

// example vf page

```
<apex:page controller="SOController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Add Products">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="p" id="orderItemTable" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!p.name}"></apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Description">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!p.description}"></apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #.#}">
                        <apex:param value="{!p.quantity}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $ ###,#00.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!p.unitPrice}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                    <apex:facet name="footer">
                        Gross Total: 
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Total Price">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $ ###,#00.00}">
                        <apex:param value="{!p.unitPrice * p.quantity}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                    <!-- footer facet is using controller method to get gross total -->
                    <apex:facet name="footer">
                        <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $ ###,#00.00}">
                            <apex:param value="{!grossTotal}" />
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Hope this helps.